# How do I set up discount for people under 18 for CiviEvent?

Tags: civievent, drupal, cividiscount

Drupal 7.39
Civi version 4.6.7

Using CiviDiscount 3.1 to add Automatic Discount to an event for folks under 18.

In researching, I saw a [PR](https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/120) referenced, that seems to address the issue, but it still doesn't work for me on two different sites.  I applied the patch but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the Auto Discount section, but in our use case, folks registering are more often than not, new unknown contacts as they register.  Do the contacts have to be logged on and/or known users for Auto Discount to work properly?

On the registration pages, we are including DOB.

However, regardless of whether we hit apply in the blank code area, the discount is not taken.

If we manually enter the code and hit apply, it works. But seems to disregard the age criteria.  If I am over 18 and have entered the code, I still get the discount.

Our discount configuration looks like this:
[image]

So the two issues I'm experiencing are:

- The discount does not apply without the code
- The discount criteria seems to be ignored and applies the discount to
  anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was not able to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Do the contacts have to be logged on and/or known users for Auto
>   Discount to work properly?

Yes I believe this is the case.